# How extract a hour from converted timzone timestamp in pandas

Tags: pandas, timestamp

At the beginning I have a UTC timestamp and from that I want to

1. convert the timestamp to "Europe/Vienna" timezone
2. want to extract the already converted hour based on "Europe/Vienna" timezone

[image]

As you can see I have already converted the timestamp to "Europe/Vienna" but when I want to extract the hour with `df_entsoe_commexch_aggregated['index'].hour` I will always get the origin hour. See below...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doing exactly what you want. `23:00:00 + 02:00` for Europe/Vienna means that it is `23:00:00` in Europe/Vienna which is 2 hours later than the origin (i.e. UTC).

As example, copied from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html):

```
>>> dti = pd.date_range(start='2014-08-01 09:00', freq='H', periods=3, tz='Europe/Berlin')
>>> dti
DatetimeIndex(['2014-08-01 09:00:00+02:00',
               '2014-08-01 10:00:00+02:00',
               '2014-08-01 11:00:00+02:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]', freq='H')
>>> dti.tz_convert('US/Central')
DatetimeIndex(['2014-08-01 02:00:00-05:00',
               '2014-08-01 03:00:00-05:00',
               '2014-08-01 04:00:00-05:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, US/Central]', freq='H')
>>> dti.tz_convert(None)
DatetimeIndex(['2014-08-01 07:00:00',
               '2014-08-01 08:00:00',
               '2014-08-01 09:00:00'],
                dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H')
```

Comment: Sorry Tobias Molenaar that was my fault. Yes, you are correct.